# Updating Existing Android App in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I've read over the google play documentation, but I didn't see where it really explained the app update process. Once you deactivate the old app and activate the new app, is it live for customers?  I was under the impression that there was a publish option after activating, but no real way for me to know besides doing it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you activate your apk on your app and click publish in the right hand corner, your app is live to customers. Note that this is only for the first publication of your app on any subsequent updates your app is already published

To publish an update, you click on the `APK files` in the top right. Then below your existing apk details you will see a button to upload a new apk. Click on this and upload your new apk file. However your users will not be getting their updates just yet, your first have to click `Activate` on your new apk file, which will appear to the right of the description of your new apk.

After you have done this it the update will go to your users, but often it will take a couple of hours for the play store to process your update and send it to your users

See here - [Android developer console app update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820688/android-developer-console-app-update)

Answer (score 0):

You upload your new `apk`, save it, activate it. That will tell you that the old one will be replaced. And publish it. It takes in average to one hour to become visible.
For more information refer to the [Update your apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) site.

Comment: It seems like once you activate the new version, that its published. Is that not true? atleast according to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9ryE6GwhmA

Comment: Yes, the new activated version will be published and available on Google Play, within about one hour.

Comment: All of these answers are incomplete. It would not have hurt to mention how to update the apk with a new version.

Comment: @JGallardo There's no need to explain how to update an `apk` because it is clearly depicted on the [Android Developer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) site.

Comment: No @slybloty, they have a lot of missing gaps information. I made several edits before i published my update that were not mentioned in their documentation. For example, if you are using Android Studio, you have to edit `versionCode` and `versionName`in **build.gradle**